# Event Receiver for View Add/Edit?

Tags: list-view, event-receivers

Is there such a thing? It's not listed as a receiver [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg749858(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg749858%28v=office.14%29.aspx) but I'm hoping I'm missing something.

Am I limited to over-riding the "OK" button (probably via JS) on the view page if I want some process to occur upon view add/edit?

Comment: you want event receiver for sharepint  "Views" (like document library views) add/edit?

Comment: yes, an SPList View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box event receiver available for SPList View  add/edit events.